# simplexml attribute to loop

Tags: xml, parsing, simplexml

i'am trying to output xml data in html table

how can i get all attributes TITLE, ARTIST in table with foreach loop without manualy writing them

> ```
> <thead>
>     <tr>
>         <th>TITLE</th>
>         <th>ARTIST</th>
>     </tr>
> </thead>
> ```

with this code i get xml data.

```
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml', 0, true);

  foreach($xml->CD as $cd)
    {

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$cd->TITLE.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$cd->ARTIST.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't look bad, however we need to know the xml in order to tell if this is correct or if not, why

Comment: in my code i get only attributes, but i want also automaticaly get tag names like "title", "artist" fot thead table

Comment: how does the cd_catalog.xml look like, are the titles in there?

Comment: you can open http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml

<CATALOG><CD><TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE><ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST><COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY><COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY><PRICE>10.90</PRICE><YEAR>1985</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE><ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST><COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY><COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY><PRICE>9.90</PRICE><YEAR>1988</YEAR></CD></CATALOG>

Comment: Most likely you don't mean attributes but elements. Please check the formal XML nomenclatura, otherwise you're question might sound a little off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to dynamically write the header and the content, for this you need a root node defined (For your example, this will be CD)

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml', 0, true);

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<thead>';
echo '    <tr>';
foreach ($xml->CD[0]->children() as $child)
{
    echo '<th>'.$child->getName().'</th>';
}
echo '    </tr>';
echo '</thead>';

foreach($xml->CD as $cd) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($cd->children() as $child) {
      echo '<td>'.$child.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';

}

echo '</table>';
```

Something like this